# Error: Missing required flag: -a, --app APP app to run command against

Tags: heroku

I am new to Heroku and I keep getting the above error - everything looks good to go when I deploy in heroku, connect to my github repo etc.. but I keep getting this error.

Its a node/express app and works exactly as I'd like locally but it won't deploy. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

For getting logs of particular heroku app, use:
heroku logs --app=app_name
For example: your app name is 'chatapp'

heroku logs -app=chatapp

Answer (score 3):

I like how the `--app` flag is "mandatory" according to the official documentation, but the lone usage example in the official documentation doesn't use the `--app` flag.

Anyway, it's not really mandatory. It's just implicit, usually. You have to tell Heroku which app you're using, with something like:

```
$ heroku git:remote -a your_app_name
```

and then it stops wondering which app to run these commands on.

Comment: Sorry for editing your post--I just wanted to separate the solution from the text so that it's easier to see.  It worked for me!  ++

Answer (score 2):

just run the command with the `--app` flag, followed by the app name.

Comment: with 7.54.1 I get "Warning: --app is not a heroku command. Did you mean apps"

Answer (score 1):

To expand a little further on this (just for the benefit of other new users encountering a similar issue) - below is an example of a command you could enter in macOS Terminal:

```
heroku logs --tail --app yourexampleservername
```

If you have deployed `yourexampleservername` to Heroku, this should then display a log.

Comment: Thanks, where did you found this ? The only [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#view-logs) I can find doesn't talk about this ...

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure this specific example was actually in their documentation - I think I just put this together based on the Heroku instructions, along with other general guides on using terminal commands.

Comment: I'm on a Mac, and this is the command/syntax I use

Answer (score 1):

you did not set git remote to your application, do that first by,

```
heroku git:remote -a your_app_name
```